# What do spider digestive fluids look like?

Tags: arachnology, digestion

What is the general appearance of the fluids that spiders use to digest their prey before they ingest it into the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most species of spiders, this liquid is thick and brownish (Brown)
This digestive juice helps spiders to feed of prey even larger than spiders.